# The delete option warns about question bans even they don't exist on MSO

Tags: bug, deleted-questions, post-ban, warning-message

When I went to delete a post:

> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge. See ["I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) for alternatives to deletion.
>
> Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being [blocked from asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). Are you sure you wish to delete?

This confuses me, because question bans don't exist on MSO.  Why would it say that?

Comment: _"because question bans don't exist on MSO"_ Where did you get that from?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't have a source, but it does check out in practice. We've had several instances of people with asking patterns that, if done on main, would've resulted in a ban (to put it mildly). I believe it doesn't apply to per-site metas in general

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362856). MSO doesn't have question bans, and in fact is the only site on the entire network that doesn't (main, or meta). There are answer bans on MSO though.

Comment: @Zoe There might be laxer rules, but IIRC it's possible to get quesiton banned from MSO. Well, at least a moderator can do that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ A moderator could *suspend* a user manually of course, but there are no automatic question bans on MSO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Question bans are only given by the system IIRC. Moderators can't hand them out, or revoke them.

Comment: Question bans can only be given by the system, and can only be removed by the system IIRC. That being said, it's still good to warn users against deleting their posts.

Comment: I suspect this is simply a case of "this is how it is *everywhere* else, it's not worth programming in the exception for MSO".

Comment: @zcoop98 MSO is quite the big community, is it really not worth the small effort of changing the text?